# cURL --dns-ipv4-addr <ip-address> needs to rebuild libcurl

Tags: curl, dns, cygwin

I'm trying to execute the following command line with cURL :

```
curl --dns-ipv4-addr http://10.67.253.23/ localhost/server-state
```

and I keep receiving the following error :

> curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.

After [some research](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html), it seems that I need to rebuild libcurl. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html at section :

> 5.9 How does libcurl resolve host names?

**Question :** Does anyone know how to rebuild libcurl so as to use --dns-ipv4-addr  option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build libcurl to use [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) for name resolving. The "normal" name resolve functions don't allow that kind of control.

This is also mentioned in the docs for [--dns-ipv4-addr](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--dns-ipv4-addr).

Comment: I actually have never build a libcurl before. The process of "building libcurl for c-ares" is unfamiliar to me. Do you know the process to do so ?

Comment: There is `configure: error: c-ares library defective or too old`. How to fix?